# Checking whether a given value exists in a binary tree

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am new to SML. I am trying to check whether a given value exist in the binary tree or not. Below is the snippet of the code. Upon execution it gives

```
Warning : match nonexhaustive (n,Node (t1, j, t2)) => ...
```

I cannot understand why it is showing this way. I guess I have covered all possible case. Can anyone give me hint or link which will be helpful to remove this warning.

```
datatype inttree = Empty | Node of inttree * int * inttree;

(*find(n,K) here n is the key that we have to find in inttree K*)
val rec find = fn(n, Node(t1,j,t2)) =>
    let 
        val t = Node(t1, j, t2)
        val compare = fn(i,j) => i = j
        val find' =
            fn (n,Empty) => false                (* if we have reached the empty node then we are not able to find the key therefore return false *)
             | (n,Node(t1,j,t2)) =>
               if compare(n,j)
               then true                         (* if value n and j are equal we have found the key n in the tree*)
               else find(n,t1) orelse find(n,t2) (* if the value is not equal check in left subtree if found return true else check in the right subtree*) 
    in
        find'(n,t)
    end;
```

Comment: You never define `find (n,Empty)` I'm not quite sure what you are doing with all these anonymous functions and `compare`. You are making it vastly more complicated than need be.

Comment: @ John Coleman if the comments help ?. Please guide me how can i make this less complicated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Given your datatype declaration, a fairly direct recursive approach is possible. Since this seems to be homework, I don't want to give a complete solution, but here is a function which has a similar flavor:

```
fun allEven Empty = true
|   allEven (Node(t1,i,t2)) =
       if i mod 2 = 1 then false
       else allEven t1 andalso allEven t2;
```

This function returns true or false depending on whether or not all integers in the tree are even. It has a basis case

```
allEven Empty = true
```

(true since there are no odd numbers in an empty tree to serve as counter-examples) and a recursive case

```
allEven (Node(t1,i,t2)) =
           if i mod 2 = 1 then false
           else allEven t1 andalso allEven t2;
```

If the integer at the node is odd, return false -- otherwise return true if the recursive call to both branches evaluate to true.

Typical runs:

```
- allEven (Node(Node(Empty,3,Empty),5,Node(Node(Empty,6,Empty),7,Empty)));
val it = false : bool
- allEven (Node(Node(Empty,4,Empty),2,Node(Node(Empty,6,Empty),8,Empty)));
val it = true : bool
```

Your function should be about this long and follow the same basic recursive pattern.

Comment: No its not homework, I am learning it to teach my friend. Thanks it is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

1. Besides `val rec`, you can also write `fun` and specify the arguments on the left-hand side of the `=`.
2. The helper function `compare` is largely redundant. You might as well use `=`. Also, what one would call a compare function in ML is usually one that returns the type *order*, having the values `LESS`, `EQUALS` and `GREATER`:

   ```
   - ​Int.compare (3, 5);
   > val it = LESS : order
   ```
3. When writing an `if ... then true else ...` or similar statement that returns the type *bool*, you might as well just use the combinators `orelse` and `andalso`. For example, you can replace the following:

   ```
   if compare(n,j)
   then true
   else find(n,t1) orelse find(n,t2)
   ```

   with:

   ```
   n = j orelse find (n, t1) orelse find (n, t2)
   ```
4. Much like the built-in functions `List.exists` and `List.all` take a function as predicate and scans a list in the attempt to prove either that at least one element exists for which this is true, or that it is true for all elements, you can make functions `treeExists` and `treeForall`:

   ```
   datatype intTree = Empty | Node of inttree * int * inttree;

   fun treeExists f Empty = false
     | treeExists f (Node (leftTree, x, rightTree)) =
       f x orelse treeExists f leftTree orelse treeExists f rightTree

   fun treeForall f Empty = true
     | treeForall f (Node (leftTree, x, rightTree)) =
       f x andalso treeForall f leftTree andalso treeExists f rightTree
   ```

   Making functions `find` and `allEven` has now become simpler:

   ```
   fun find (x, tree) = treeExists (fn y => x = y) tree
   fun allEven tree = treeForall (fn x => x mod 2 = 0) tree
   ```

   since all the recursion has been left to new library functions.

   In a similar way, you can make `treeMap` and `treeFold`:

   ```
   fun treeMap f Empty = Empty
     | treeMap f (Node (leftTree, x, rightTree)) = ...

   fun treeFold f e Empty = e
     | treeFold f e (Node (leftTree, x, rightTree)) = ...
   ```

   They could be used to find the largest absolute value in a tree:

   ```
   fun maxAbsTree tree =
       treeFold Int.max 0 (treeMap Int.abs tree)
   ```

Comment: Your higher-order tree function (`treeExists` and `treeForall`) are nice and are a good illustration of functional programming.

Comment: @Simon Shine thanks  for enlightening. Your methods are crystal clear to understand. Thanks very much